# Uniform convergence to exponential on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to know if there exists unbounded  domains of the complex plane  $\mathbb{C}$ on which the sequence of functions
$\left((1-z/n)^{-n}\right)_{n\geq 1}$ converges uniformely to the exponential function.

Answer (score 1):

It does so on any compact subset of the plane.

Comment: Sorry I haven't mentionned in the question it but I  am rather interested in unbounded domains of the complex plane on which the convergence is uniform. Does that exist?